How to show multicolor on slider using d3-simple-slider.js
I am using d3-simple slider and want to show multicolor on slider i.e.

From Range 0-9 it should be blue and 9 to 26 is orange and for range 26-60 color should be red and If I move handle which is currently pointing to 26 then slide it towards left then red color should follow it ,similarly for otehr handle too.Can someone please help in regarding this?
 const rangeSvg = d3.select('figure#rangeContainer')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 350) 
      .attr('height', height);

    const segmentWidth = 90; 

    // Create the first slider
    const rangeSlider = rangeSvg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(10,30)'); // Position the first slider

    // Call your slider function to draw the first slider
    rangeSlider.call(sliderHorizontal()

      .min(1)
      .max(60)
      .step(1)
      .default([6,36])
      .tickValues([1, 6, 36, 60])
      .width(segmentWidth * 3)
      .handle(d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(100)())
      .fill('orange') // Apply the gradient here
      .on('onchange', selectedPeriod => {
       let fileAgingPeriod = selectedPeriod.map(Math.round);
        this.activeValue = fileAgingPeriod[0];
        this.obsoleteValue = tfileAgingPeriod[1];
        this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
      })
    );

    rangeSlider.select('.track-inset')
      .attr('stroke', '#54A7FF');
    //  .attr('stroke-dasharray',230);

    rangeSlider.selectAll('.handle')
      .attr('fill', '#54A7FF');


Are you sure that's possible with a component that's called "simple slider"? You may need to modify the component itself.

I think it is possible.

Are you able to target the specific SVG elements with CSS? Providing a code example of this specific slider would be helpful rather than just a screenshot.

@jjroley please check code above mentioned.

Here's a little d3/SVG trickery.  It clones the slider's "inset" to break them into two pieces, one before the selection, colored blue, and one after, colored red.  The two insets then dynamically resize as you move the slider.


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-simple-slider"></script>

<p id="value"></p>
<div id="slider"></div>

<script>
  const min = 1,
    max = 60;

  // function to dynamically resize
  setInsetLens = (selection) => {
    d3.select('#before-inset')
    .attr('x2', (selection[0] / (min + max)) * initialWidth);
    d3.select('#after-inset')
    .attr('x1', (selection[1] / (min + max)) * initialWidth);
  };

  var slider = d3
    .sliderHorizontal()
    .min(min)
    .max(max)
    .step(1)
    .default([6, 36])
    .tickValues([1, 6, 36, 60])
    .width(90 * 3)
    .handle(d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(100)())
    .fill('orange')
    .on('onchange', setInsetLens);

  d3.select('#slider')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 500)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(30,30)')
    .call(slider);

  // clone the inset, set the colors and get its initial width
  const initialWidth = d3.select('.track-inset')
    .attr('id', 'before-inset')
    .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
    .clone()
    .attr('id', 'after-inset')
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .node()
    .getBBox()
    .width;

  // set initial size
  setInsetLens([6,36]);

</script>




Thanks a lot it worked i have integerate it in my angular code and productised it.Many thanks for your efforts really appreciate it.I learnt a lot from your solution.
